# Visual Studio 2010 Won't Auto-Indent Lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010, used to auto indent my lines, and now suddenly it won't do that,
for example, when I created a method, it looked like that:

```
public static void Foo (int FooInt)
{
    // Some methods stuff...
}
```

but now, it looks like that:

```
public static void Foo (int FooInt)
{
// Some method stuff...
}
```

I can't find any answer for that, what can I do?

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 64 Bit

Update: Turns out my problem on resides on C#, when I am trying it on a C++ project, indentation work perfectly...
Any suggestions?

**Update**:

Problem was solved, unexpectedly by re-installing Windows.

Comment: Does the project compile? Is your code free of errors? What if you request VS to do the formatting by pressing Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D?

Comment: @CodeCaster, No code is ever free of errors!

Comment: Yes, it build successfully, its a newly created untouched project, I have tried Ctrl+K and Ctrl+D, it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Restart Visual Studio, or maybe the PC, and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: I swear I did all of these, what else can I do?

Comment: Do you have ReSharper or any other plugin for code indenting installed? Maybe that's expired or broken.

Comment: In my case it usually works correctly, but at some point, like if it was open for several hours, it stops indenting correctly. Then I restart Visual Studio, so it works again. It has nothing to do with build errors. Any other ideas are very welcome. Using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: It's been more than two years, on Windows 10 I still have the same issue. Why do people use Microsoft products..

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem and after changing Indenting from Block to Smart it started working![image]

Answer (score 3):

Check your indentation settings in Visual Studio - `Tools|Options..` => `Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Indentation`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the project wont build the auto indent wont work.

The short command for indent in VS 2010 is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: @Andrea try to make your edits more substancial, until you have the edit privilage all your edits go through the review system which means several have to spend time checking the edits, so it is not good to do such minor changes.

Comment: @MrD: While edits should be substantial, I would never discourage a user from editing, even if it has to hit the review queue. I think Andrea saw fit to highlight the key combination and in-so-doing has clarified the answer without changing its meaning, which is a good edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is precisely, but I'll take a shot in the dark.  Under Tools->Options->C#->Tabs, what is the value?

[image: Indent Size]

Comment: The value is 4, same as the picture

Comment: Well, if you really think its a settings problem, you can always do something like this.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/16/reset-all-your-development-settings-vstipenv0023.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution to this problem if all of the settings in VS2010 seem to be correct is to check for characters from other character encodings.  For example, if one accidentally places left and right quotes inside the source code, it could prevent visual studio from automatically formatting your code.  Sometimes you get an error to help you identify such a situation, sometimes it is more latent and a pain to find.