# Visual Studio, Python not auto-indenting

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This is probably a simple issue but something is wrong with my Python tools for visual studio. When I first started using VS2015 for Python it would auto-indent whenever I used a colon. Now VS2015 is just acting like a text editor with syntax highlighting. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Python tools but that did not work. How do I fix Visual Studio to auto-style as I write Python again?

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462233/visual-studio-2010-wont-auto-indent-lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://stevedower.id.au/blog/smart-indentation-for-python/

> However, the most common (and default) mode is “Smart.” Unlike the other two modes, which are built into the editor, smart indentation is provided by a language service (which are also responsible for providing syntax highlighting and completions). Because they are targeted to a specific language, they can help the programmer by automatically adding and removing extra indentation in ways that make sense.

Answer (score 32):

`Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> Python -> Tabs` and set it to `Smart`

Comment: Thank you.. that was driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Visual Studio

```
Tools -> Option -> Text Editor -> Python -> Tabs
```

- Disable the "Keep the Tabs"
- Select "Insert Spaces"
- Select "Indenting" as "Smart"