# Visual Studio 2015 won't auto-indent lines correctly in All Languages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.x - update 3) and no matter what I try, I can't get **All Languages** to do *Smart* indenting. I go into `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Tabs` and set it like so:

[image]

I've got a handler file open in VS (.ashx file) with inline code:

[image]

Notice that when I position my cursor right after the opening curly brace and hit `Enter`, the cursor goes to the next line, but indents too far over. This does not happen when a c# file is being edited. When I go back into Options to see what is going on, I am surprised to find Smart formatting cleared:

[image]

It doesn't matter how many times I re-select Smart, it doesn't honor it, and it clears it again. I don't believe ASHX file types have their own registered Text Editor type in VS, but maybe it does, listed under something unexpected, and that is overwriting it. I can't see any types that even resemble 'handler', or etc.

I even tried hand-editing the .vssettings file to enable Smart, but it still doesn't work, and Smart is cleared again when I go into Options.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462233/visual-studio-2010-wont-auto-indent-lines) and tried to follow it, but my case is a little different.

How can I get the same indent behavior on my ASHX file as I get with .cs files, so that when hitting Enter after a line, it goes to the correct place on the next line, as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Smart indenting is not applicable for all languages and hence the check is disappeared for All Languages, but the option is checked for C# ,html etc. for any applicable language.

Please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs?view=vs-2015

Comment: Try to format the code in .ashx file using ctrl+K,D and it should do it.